# Android app showing double layout when i start my app with instant run

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a very big problem with android application. I searched alot but cannot found any solution about this or maybe it is the new error with me that's why there are no any solution.

I have a viewpager in my app and have 5 fragments on that app. so let's assume i am on the 3 fragment and click on instant run then my 3rd fragment will be double or show in all other viewpager fragments layout. this sometimes also happen wiht my users when my app destroy itself without any crash error.

i have attached the screen shot please solve this big problem thanks.

first image

[image]

second image

[image]

updated my libraries to these but still have same issue.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
```

Updated: Finally i solved my problem. It was not problem with recyclerview. It was problem with main fragment which have viewpager fragments. So i checked if mainfragment is null create otherwise not create.

Comment: Are you using recycler view?

Comment: yes i am using recycler view.

Comment: i am using these libraries.

compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'

Comment: Which Android Studio version you are using right now?

Comment: android studio 2.1.3 stable

Comment: are you adding your fragments or replacing them?

Comment: there is no need to add or replace fragment. i am using viewpager. in viewpager we just pass the fragment list into viewpager adapter and set that adapter to viewpager.

Comment: Did find any solution to this ??

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, new SearchFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

please replace this with:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, new SearchFragment());
transaction.commit();
```